# How to prevent video from pausing when exiting picture-in-picture mode in Safari?

Tags: reactjs, picture-in-picture

I'm trying to implement a Picture-in-Picture mode for a video conference app I'm building with Reactjs. The code I'm using looks something like:

`PIP.js`

```js
export const canPIP = () =>
  "pictureInPictureEnabled" in document && document.pictureInPictureEnabled;

export const isInPIP = () => Boolean(document.pictureInPictureElement);

const supportsOldSafariPIP = () => {
  const video = document.createElement("video");

  return (
    canPIP() &&
    // @ts-ignore
    video.webkitSupportsPresentationMode &&
    // @ts-ignore
    typeof video.webkitSetPresentationMode === "function"
  );
};

const supportsModernPIP = () => {
  const video = document.createElement("video");

  return (
    canPIP() &&
    video.requestPictureInPicture &&
    typeof video.requestPictureInPicture === "function"
  );
};
export const supportsPIP = () => supportsOldSafariPIP() || supportsModernPIP();

export const openPIP = async (video) => {
  if (isInPIP()) return;

  if (supportsOldSafariPIP()) {
    // @ts-ignore
    await video?.webkitSetPresentationMode("picture-in-picture");
  }
  if (supportsModernPIP()) {
    await video?.requestPictureInPicture();
  }
};

export const closePIP = async (video) => {
  if (!isInPIP()) return;

  if (supportsOldSafariPIP()) {
    // @ts-ignore
    await video?.webkitSetPresentationMode("inline");
  }
  if (supportsModernPIP()) {
    await document?.exitPictureInPicture();
  }
};
```

Hook `usePIP`

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { closePIP, isInPIP, openPIP } from "./PIP";

const defaultOptions = {
  autoPIP: true,
};

const usePIP = (videoElement, options = defaultOptions) => {
  const disablePIP = useCallback(async () => {
    await closePIP(videoElement.current).catch(console.warn);
  }, [videoElement]);

  const enablePIP = useCallback(async () => {
    await openPIP(videoElement.current).catch(console.warn);
  }, [videoElement]);

  const handleVisibility = useCallback(async () => {
    if (document.visibilityState === "visible") await disablePIP();
    else await enablePIP();
  }, [disablePIP, enablePIP]);

  const togglePIP = useCallback(async () => {
    if (isInPIP()) await disablePIP();
    else await enablePIP();
  }, [enablePIP, disablePIP]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!options.autoPIP) return;
    const video = videoElement.current;

    if (video && "autoPictureInPicture" in video)
      // @ts-ignore
      video.autoPictureInPicture = true;

    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibility);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibility);
    };
  }, [options.autoPIP, videoElement, handleVisibility]);

  return {
    enablePIP,
    disablePIP,
    togglePIP,
  };
};

export default usePIP;
```

And I make use of this `togglePIP` in a `useEffect` where I listen to a state:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   togglePIP();
}, [isPictureInPictureEnabled])
```

This works perfectly fine in Chrome where if I try to close the PiP mode from the PiP itself, but the video gets paused when I tried it out on Safari, which is bad for video conference.

Something that might help as well is that I set up the video conference controls through a `useEffect` as well as such:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler("togglemicrophone", () => {
        console.log('User clicked "Toggle Mic" icon.');
        if (isAllowUnmute) {
          navigator.mediaSession.setMicrophoneActive(!isUseMicrophone);
          dispatch(setUseMicrophone(!isUseMicrophone));
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(
        'Warning! The "togglemicrophone" media session action is not supported.'
      );
    }

    try {
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler("togglecamera", () => {
        console.log('User clicked "Toggle Camera" icon.');
        navigator.mediaSession.setCameraActive(!isUseVideo);
        dispatch(setUseVideo(!isUseVideo));
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(
        'Warning! The "togglecamera" media session action is not supported.'
      );
    }
  }, [isUseMicrophone, isUseVideo]);
```